# console.log() in VS Code with vitest and vitest test runner

Tags: visual-studio-code, vitest

I'm using `vitest` in VS Code with the official Vitest test runner plugin.

All works as expected, but any `console.log()` statements don't seem to appear anywhere.

Not in the VScode test results tab, or the test output tab, not in the Testing panel...

I've also tried importing log directly, same result (no output):

```
import { log } from "console";
```

Am I missing a configuration option?

Comment: Have a look at the silent flag https://vitest.dev/config/#silent

Comment: I'm facing the same behavior, did you find a way?

Comment: also having this issue, unbelievable such a basic functionality like printing to console doesn't work

Comment: Could you please show us how you're running the command? We need to see the flags you're using either in the `package.json` or the terminal.

Comment: I'm having a similar issue. Just using the vitest vs code extension and clicking the "play" icon on the test file to run the test. Can't see any silent configurations anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue where console.logs weren't always in the test output with Vitest. In my case the issue was not awaiting an async function I called in a test. I didn't need the return value so I didn't think it would matter, but it's important for the test runner to wait until every function it runs is actually finished.